# Magnolia CMS: How to (trigger) push new added content to a external resource (PHP or bash-script)

Tags: api, rest, groovy, magnolia

My main concern is more or less what you can extract from the headline:
I want to 'inform' a external resource, in my case a "php-script" (php is maybe running on the same enviroment like magnolia, bash script is possible too), if i add a new 'page' in magnolia (i need the hole content of the new page, means what you can get if you use the JCR).
(With page i mean a page you can 'publish')

I'm not really new with Magnolia and i now there are some usable mechanics like:

- The Magnolia-REST-API (since Magnolia 5? see -> https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/REST+API)
- Magnolia-Commands
- Groovy-Scrips as Commands (?)

The question is, is my following explanation a possible way to do this?

---

How i understand what maybe should be possible:

- You can write a command with Groovy
- this command can execute a external php or bash script
- this command can get the last added page from magnolia (the content)
- You can add this command maybe to the publishing or the creation of a page

---

What would be really nice is if anyone can say is this a possible way and when yes
how can i pass in the groovy script the last added magnolia page and all needed informations?

I never write something in groovy before...

Maybe there is another (possible better) way to do this... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are really looking for is [Magnolia's Observation Module](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Observation+module). With the help of the module, you can configure even listener that will be notified of every operation of interest (page creation in your case) and invoke any command such as one that would make http request to your external php-script or one that would trigger bash script in your underlying shell. Both such commands should be easy to write in groovy and there's plenty of examples outside for that.
When you look at Observation module, check out in details "sendMailOnPageChanges" example that does pretty much what you want (it sends mail when new page is added or existing one is modified). 
If you want to export content and send it as part of your notification, you can use `info.magnolia.importexport.DataTransporter.executeExport(OutputStream, boolean, boolean, Session, String, String, String)` method to do the job.

HTH,
Jan